# How can I find httpd.conf on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-10.04, httpd.conf

How can I find httpd.conf on Ubuntu 10.04. I just got server with lack of information.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try typing this in the console:

```
locate httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Query the package manamager.

```
dpkg -L apache2 | grep "conf"
```

or

```
dpkg -L apache | grep "conf"
```

Comment: locate could not answer but the package manager could. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

run httpd -V It should show HTTPD_ROOT as well as SERVER_CONFIG_FILE. From there you know where is your httpd.config file. read details at this article [how to unset apache header](http://www.shanison.com/2012/07/05/unset-apache-response-header-protect-your-server-information/)